# Is there a possible way to have a row from a meta data table with a certain meta key automatically inserted into a new row?

Tags: mysql, join, hyperlink, automation

I currently have a MYSQL query that searches a usermeta table and matches emails up with customer emails from another table, then creates a row in the usermeta table with the corresponding customer id. However, is there a way to have this done automatically every time these types of rows are inserted into the customer table?

Or at the very least, is there a way to send ALL rows from one table to the other automatically with the emails being what the two tables share in common, then after it matches the email it assigns the correct user id based on the userdata table?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and show the schema of your `usermeta` table and the `other_table`? Please also add examples of the data you have and the data you want. It shouldn't be hard to create the appropriate database trigger or an `insert` or `update` statement, but without the information about the tables we can't help you here.

Comment: You can use [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) do run code when you insert/update/delete rows, and [`insert ... select`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) to insert lots of rows (that you are able to write a select for) at once into a table. To get a more precise answer, you would need to add your current code, table and sample data and expected result. In general you should make sure you are not getting in trouble duplicating data (e.g. check what happens if the email in the original table changes after you created metadata)